# Laravel 5.4 skip first value in Pluck array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, pluck

I have this query

```
$orderStates = OrderState::listsTranslations( 'states' )->pluck( 'states', 'id' )->toArray();
```

which will output something like

```
array:3 [▼
  1 => "waiting"
  2 => "agreed"
  3 => "canceled"
]
```

I need to skip the first one to be something like

```
array:3 [▼
      2 => "agreed"
      3 => "canceled"
    ]
```

How this can be done please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks for Namoshek guide but `skip(1)` didn't work with this but `slice(1)` did

Here is the last query

```
$orderStates = OrderState::listsTranslations( 'states' )
                                 ->pluck( 'states', 'id' )
                                 ->slice( 1 )
                                 ->toArray();
```

Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways you can achieve this. One that doesn't seem very consistent to me would be to use `skip(1)` (this expects the query to sort by `id` and that always the entry with `id = 1` needs to be skipped):

```
$orderStates = OrderState::listsTranslations( 'states' )
    ->skip(1)
    ->pluck( 'states', 'id' )
    ->toArray();
```

An alternative might be to use `whereNotIn()` to exclude specific `ids`:

```
$orderStates = OrderState::listsTranslations( 'states' )
    ->whereNotIn('id', [1])
    ->pluck( 'states', 'id' )
    ->toArray();
```

You could also use `where('id', '!=', 1)` instead of `whereNotIn('id', [1])` or `skip(1)`, but personally I think that `whereNotIn` offers the most extensibility for the future.

Comment: Thanks for response but didn't work with me try skip(1) got `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 1' at line 1 (SQL: select `order_states`.`id`, `order_state_translations`.`states` from `order_states` left join `order_state_translations` on `order_state_translations`.`order_state_id` = `order_states`.`id` where `order_state_translations`.`locale` = ar offset 1)`

Comment: Hm yeah, it is actually a limitation of MySQL you are running into there. If you would add a `limit(100)` (or any other number that is greater than the amount of records you want to receive from the database), it will work. But as this is hacky and adds some functionality you might not be able to debug in future, better stay away from it.